# working on multiple tables with one view in mvc 5 entity framework and do dynamic view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one dropdown box and I bind 2 values: **passport** and **pan**.

When first time page loads, I want to get one view to enter **fname** and **lname**. Below to that I have dropdown. 
If I select **passport** from dropdown, I want to get fields to enter passport issued date, expiry date etc. 
And if I select **pan card**, I want to get fields to select pan card number,expiry date etc.

All these should happen in one view. I am using entity framework. 
Finally I want to save details to separate tables.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Make a viewmodel for your view and post all values of the view to controller using that viewmodel
 Once you get all form fields at the controller make instance of each table(entity) and map values that you are getting in viewmodel.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // table 1(Table1Entity is your class)
          Table1Entity a = Table1Entity();
           a.property = model.property1;
            db.Table1Entity.add(a);
          //  db.SaveChanges();

            // table 2
            Table2Entity b =Table2Entity();
            b.property= model.property2;
             db.Table2Entity.add(b);
            db.SavChanges();

  // so on for all other tables entity

  return   RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Your viewmodel

```
 Public class MyViewModel{

       public string property1{get; set;}

       public string property2{get;set;}
 }
```

Your view(form pointing to controller, add action and controller name)

```
  @model MyViewModel

 <form>
    @Html.InputFor(m=>m.property1)
    //all other form fields
 </form>
```